# Function Across Multiple Controllers with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I am trying to implement an AngularJS service that takes a date.prototype function and passes it to multiple controllers. I inject the services in the controllers but for some reason it isn't working. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

**services.js:**

```
var appStuff = angular.module('services', [])

appStuff.service ('ChronService', function () 
{

   Date.prototype.formatSubtractDate = function (x) 
   {
     var myTime = new Date();
     myTime.setFullYear(myTime.getFullYear) - x);
     return myTime;
   };
   Date.prototype.formatAddDate = function (x) 
   {
     var myTime = new Date();
     myTime.setFullYear(myTime.getFullYear) + x);
     return myTime;
   };
});
```

**oneController.js:**

```
angular.module('oneController', [])
.controller('oneCtrl', function ($scope, ChronService) {
    $scope.subtractYears = ChronService.Date().formatSubtractDate(4);

    if ($scope.subtractYears >= 2004) {
      console.log("right")
    }
    else 
    {
      console.log("incorrect")
    }
});
```

**twoController.js**

```
angular.module('oneController', [])
.controller('oneCtrl', function ($scope, ChronService) {
    $scope.addYears = ChronService.Date().formatAddDate(25);

    if ($scope.addYears < 1996) {
      console.log("right")
    }
    else 
    {
      console.log("incorrect")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to add the dependency for the module to the modules for the controllers.
angular.module('oneController', ['services'])

currently your modules for your  controllers don't know where the service is located.